# Binary Multiplication - Negative number X Negative number

Tags: math, binary

Please don't tell me to convert the numbers to positive and attempt it as - X - = +

The number is -3 (101)

-3 X -3 = +9

How can this sum be done in binary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative integers are usually stored in 2's complement representation, which means that as an m-bit number -x is stored as 2<sup>m</sup>-x. This is where the name **two's** complement comes from: adding x results in a complete power of two.

Assuming we use 32 bits, -3 is stored as 2<sup>32</sup>-3 = 4294967293.

So, -3 × -3 = 4294967293 × 4294967293 = 18446744047939747849. But this number doesn't fit into 32 bits. It overflows, and we are left with its last 32 bits. Those bits naturally encode the number 9.

You want to see it in binary? Ok. -3 is 2<sup>32</sup>-3 is 11111111111111111111111111111101<sub>2</sub>.

```
11111111111111111111111111111101×11111111111111111111111111111101 =
 1111111111111111111111111111101000000000000000000000000000001001
        (32 msb)                         (32 lsb)
```

The lowest 32 bits of the result are 00000000000000000000000000001001<sub>2</sub>, which is the number 9.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Although, I would like to know more about the 2m-x as the book i refer to doesn't mention it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Calculations with m-bit integers is implemented as calculations modulo 2^m, so -x and -x+2^m are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for methods to perform a multiplication for values expressed in [**2's complement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)...

This [**web page from Karen Miller, at U. of Wisconsin**](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-1/beyond354/int.mult.html) provides several of these methods, including ones that do not require to first convert the numbers to their inverses.